# Validating e-mail from specific domains with RSV jquery plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, email-validation

I'm trying to use Ben Keen's RSV Jquery plug-in to validate an e-mail address submitted through a registration form: users are only allowed to submit an e-mail address that belongs to a specific domain. I thought that using the plugin's reg_exp rule could be a solution, but I can't get it to work. 
I'm a jquery newbie, so I'm probably making some very silly mistake: can someone point me to the right direction?

Here's the code I'm trying to use, adapted from one of Keen's demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // a custom onComplete handler to prevent form submits for the demo
  function myOnComplete()
  {
    alert("The form validates! (normally, it would submit the form here).");
    return false;
  }

    var rules = [];

// standard form fields

rules.push("reg_exp,reg_exp_field1,/@mydomain\.tld$/gi,Please enter your valid e-mail (e.g. \"@mydomain\.tld\")");


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo_form3").RSV({
    onCompleteHandler: myOnComplete,
    rules: rules
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Using the code above, when I submit a valid e-mail address, that is an address ending with @mydomain.tld I always get an alert. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written RSV for many lines of code. It's very powerful. 
However, you used it incorrectly.

1. you should define a customized function instead of its default email-format validation method.
2. you should put that "customized function" mentioned above into the validation array, but not put it in "myOnComplete" method, this method only called when all the validations are passed.
3. in RSV, a customized function only should return "true"(when passed) or "an Array"(when failed). but in the example above, you implemented as "return false".

Whatever, you have solved your problem in another way. :-) that's good.

Comment: Hi Siwei, thanks for pointing out my mistake. When it comes to jquery/javascript I'm a complete newbie, and I'm learning by trial and error.
Thanx for replying to my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, after further researche I found a simpler solution: following the advice in [this forum thread](http://webmasterpals.com/showthread.php?t=2219) I used jqueryValidate instead of rsv plug-in and added custom validate method. 
I'm posting here my solution, maybe it could be useful for some other jquery newbie like me!

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

$.validator.addMethod("gmail", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[\w-\.]+@(gmail\.com|yahoo\.com)+$/i.test(value);
}, "Email address must contain gmail or yahoo addresses."); 

    $("#register_member_form").validate();
});
```